# How to integrate multiple apps into one using Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm working on a project where **I've to integrate two Android apps into a single app, using Android Studio IDE**.

For example, I have App_A and App_B; these two Android apps are from two separate vendors. Now I've to integrate App_B inside App_A. Hence there would be a single AndroidManifest.xml file (of App_A) with MainActivity (launcher) and a single apk would be generated.

So far, I've imported App_B as a module inside App_A. Now, I can run each module separately. But I've to create a single apk file comprising of two modules.

I've searched in different Android forums in the Internet and so far I've not found any suitable solution.

First of all, I want to know **whether it's possible to integrate two Android apps from two different vendors into a single Android app**. If it's possible then please provide a solution to this issue. Also it would be a great help if you can send me your suggestions, ideas or any links regarding this issue.

Thanks & regards,

Debu

Comment: `I want to know whether it's possible to integrate two Android apps from two different vendors into a single Android app.` **No**, it's not. Unless these apps aren't open source and you can modify their sources to mix them into one. Or unless you want to turn yourself into a **pirate** and decompile them yourself.

Comment: Yes, you should. It will probably require some time to learn the logic of both apps (`analyzing is always harder than creating`, since each of us reasons in a different way).

Comment: @Debu see my answer below, it should solve your requirement, let me know if any issues faced!

Comment: Did any solution work for you ? @Debu I am searching a way to do the same thing. Can you please suggest ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that:

1. Import the third party app's source code as a separate library module.
2. Modify the `dependencies` section of your Main module's `build.gradle` file to include the third party module as a dependency like this:

   `compile project(':your_module_name_here')`

Comment: Hi Asif, thanks for your reply. I also thought that I can create a separate library module. I would try this.

Comment: Did this solution work for you ? @Debu I am searching a way to do the same thing. Can you please suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

You can launch other apps activities from your main app. It's the same as integrating facebook, you declare `com.facebook.LoginActivity` in your manifest. In Project_A manifest file declare activity from Project_B. FB eg:

```
 <activity
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Vinted.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Also don't forget to include Project_B in gradle, FB eg:

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1')
```

Comment: To integrate FaceBook, there is a specific API, though.

Comment: The main point is that you can use Activity from other app in your main app

Comment: That's only opening another app, not merging two apps into a single unit.

Comment: You can make this look like single app. Whats is exactly merging two apps?

Comment: Probably, integrating the **methods** from both. And possibly do an UI "mash-up".

Comment: @ Tadas Valaitis - Hi Tadas, thanks for your reply. As Der has mentioned, I want to integrate two apps into a single app. I think, it's not same as launching an external app (e.g. Facebook) from my MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to integrate App_A and App_B, just as your case, you could do like this: `select App_A and right-click`--->`Open Module Settings`--->`Modules`--->`App_A`--->`Dependencies`--->`Plus`--->`Module Dependency`--->`select App_B` and then `OK`.
But if you want export only one `APK` from the two `modules`, I am afraid you have to add `activity&service&broadcast` thing of `AndroidManifest.xml` of `App_B` into that of `App_A` manully. and delete `AndroidManifest.xml` of `App_B`.

Comment: Hi SilentKnight, thanks for your reply. I'll try this approach.

Comment: @Abhishek - As Asif had mentioned above, the solution to this problem is to make App_B as a lib module inside App_A (hence, I had accepted that answer too).